# print a null-terminated string in windbg

Tags: windbg

Which windbg command will print string in a executable ? For now , I'm using db command but it's output is very inconvenient to copy and paste . I also tried ds command , seems not work . Many thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For single byte strings, use `da`. For unicode strings, use `du`.